# Auto increase when id is null but apply the assigned value when id is not null for hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a entity as below (Getter and Setter are ignored).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "idGenerator", strategy = "increment")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( generator = "idGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

**What I need is:

1) id == null (id is not assigned), the strategy is auto increment

2) id != null (id is assigned), persist the entity with assigned value**

For my code, id generation would be auto increment anytime. And I'm wondering if hibernate can support the above requirement with configuration? Or I need to implement it manually? Database I'm using is MySql.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing an [*auto increment* column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows...
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>      id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>      name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
>     ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
>     ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
>
> SELECT * FROM animals;
> ```
>
> Which returns:
>
> ```
> +----+---------+
> | id | name    |
> +----+---------+
> |  1 | dog     |
> |  2 | cat     |
> |  3 | penguin |
> |  4 | lax     |
> |  5 | whale   |
> |  6 | ostrich |
> +----+---------+
> ```
>
> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers. If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers. When you insert any other value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value.

Comment: Yes, the field of id in my table has been set up as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, I can get what you said in native SQL. However, if I remove the generate strategy in annotation of hibernate, I would get Exception with message `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()`,  is there more advice?

Comment: @Junjie: A quick search suggests the relevant Hibernate annotation is `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`.

Comment: Get unexpected exception when set up `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` but works with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.  Thanks very much for saving my time.

Comment: I can't seem to make this work with postgres. Anyone managed to do so?

Comment: @olivakyle - Curiously enough I just recently had reason to learn this about Postgres. They (and Oracle) call these "[sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createsequence.html)" and you can create them separately or as part of a [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html), for instance `CREATE TABLE x (id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1), value INT);` creates a table with an auto-assigned `id`. The options (in `()`) are all optional and I've shown the defaults for the two I specified.